# Ram shoots every third penalty to goal.If he gets chance to shoot all 5 penalty shots.What is the probability that he converts (does) exactly 3 goals.

Tags: probability

> Ram shoots every third penalty to goal.If he gets chance to shoot all 5 penalty shots.What is the probability that he converts (does) exactly 3 goals.

My Approach:

p(Ram for every 3rd goal)=1/3

p(Not scoring goal)=2/3

p(he gets exactly 3 goals)=(1/3)^3*(2/3)^2

Is this Right?

Comment: You state "Ram shoots every third penalty to goal."  In Mathematics we read very carefully and leave nothing to ambiguity.  So, as stated, the probability is zero that he will get exactly three goals in a series of five sequential shots.  (Think about it... he will only ever get exactly 1 or exactly 2 goals.)  I think you meant instead "On average, 1/3 of Ram's shots are goals; 2/3 are not goals."  Very different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have calculated is the probability Ram scores the first three shots and misses the last two shots, or that the result is $SSSMM$.

There are other ways to score exactly three shots. How many? They are the sequences of $3$ S and $2$ $M$. They are $\binom{2+3}{2}=\frac{5!}{2!3!}=10$.

They are the following:

$SSSMM$

$SSMSM$

$SMSSM$

$MSSSM$

$SSMMS$

$SMSMS$

$MSSMS$

$SMMSS$

$MSMSS$

$MMSSS$

Since each has probability $\frac{1}{3}^3\frac{2}{3}^2=\frac{4}{243}$ and they are all mutually exclusive we find that the probability of scoring exactly $3$ scores is $10\cdot\frac{4}{243}\approx 0.1646$

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a Binomial distribution. You will need to multiply your answer by $^5 C_3=\frac {5!}{3!2!}$ because there are that many different ways of scoring exactly 3 goals.